# How can I get data from iframe with ghost.py?

Tags: python, iframe, web-scraping, ghost.py

I'm trying to scrape site with iframe so when I do `ghost.show()`
I see my result normally so iframe is filled, but after when I do `ghost.content`
it returns iframe empty, think it's done for security but how can I get this data?
Thank you and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can descend into your frame this way:

```
ghost = Ghost()
ghost.frame('<your frame name>')

g.content  # Your frame content

g.frame()  # ascent back to root frame
```

http://ghost-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#ghost.Ghost.frame

Comment: thank you Jeanphix for this great lib.Can you say what must be in '<your frame name>', I mean how I get it?

Comment: You can now pass the iframe `name` attribute value or the iframe index. https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/commit/0af36cff0dd39d5e05f6d012868907905d01a7a6#diff-9abba704801dc0e59ef9b8874f1c6b98L437